# Collision with Phaser Arcade physics engine

Tags: javascript, game-physics, phaser-framework

I am trying to make a game with Phaser Arcade Physics where you control a sprite and try to avoid objects with arrow keys. However, I have problems making collision happen between those objects and the sprite.

My code:
https://jsfiddle.net/o445dt44/

It is specifically at line 69 in the JSFiddle, I would like you to take a look.

```
//game.physics.arcade.collide(sprite, enemy, enemy2, enemy3);
```

This should usually do the job of the collision, however it is not.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FYI for the future, your JSFiddle is missing an external reference to Phaser. There's a CDN version you can include at https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/phaser/2.6.2/phaser.min.js, for example.

Second, you're actually not using the collide function correctly. Per [the documentation](http://phaser.io/docs/2.6.2/Phaser.Physics.Arcade.html#collide) it's actually `collide(object1, object2, collideCallback, processCallback, callbackContext)`.

I've created [a forked version](https://jsfiddle.net/strivinglife/oh38dw06/1/) that setups collisions properly. In particular the following changes were made:

The enemies need to be setup at the same level as the `sprite`.

```
var enemy;
var enemy2;
var enemy3;
```

Next, in your update, given how you have things setup, you need to setup collisions between all objects individually:

```
game.physics.arcade.collide(sprite, enemy);
game.physics.arcade.collide(sprite, enemy2);
game.physics.arcade.collide(sprite, enemy3);
game.physics.arcade.collide(enemy, enemy2);
game.physics.arcade.collide(enemy, enemy3);
game.physics.arcade.collide(enemy2, enemy3);
```

The alternative, and better way to do this, would be to setup your enemies as a group and then have your sprite collide with the group.

There's an [official Sprite Vs Group example](https://phaser.io/examples/v2/arcade-physics/sprite-vs-group) that covers this. If you want the enemies to collide, you could then setup the group to collide with itself.

```
game.physics.arcade.collide(enemies, enemies);
```

Comment: Glad to help! Best of luck with Phaser; I've found it to be a great little framework. :)